# How do I use one series of arguments vs another series when calling script?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

newish programmer here. This is my first bash script...

This is a script to backup EBS volumes on AWS. I can currently call the script with the `backup` argument. Or I can call it with the `delete` argument followed by a numerical argument (i.e. `3`), which deletes any snapshots with the 'backup-script' description that is as old or older than the number of days passed as the numerical argument passed after `delete`.

Unfortunately, no matter whether I call `backup` or `delete`, either one is the first argument and goes to the `ACTION` variable, and whatever my second argument is it goes to the `AGE` variable.

Proof:

```
~  bash -x backup backup vol-e5bf623b
+ ACTION=backup
+ AGE=vol-e5bf623b
+ VOLUME=
+ '[' -z backup ']'
+ '[' backup = delete ']'
+ '[' backup = backup ']'
+ '[' -z ']'
+ echo 'Please provide a volume id that you would like to backup'
Please provide a volume id that you would like to backup
+ exit 3
```

What's not obvious to me, is how to do it differently so that when I call `script_name backup vol-f00bar` that vol-id is passed to a variable (like `VOLUME`) and then passed to my `backup_ebs` function.

I am going this route to run the script with different cron tasks to handle rotation policy of backups.

```
#!/bin/bash

ACTION=$1
AGE=$2
VOLUME=$3

# When calling script, if an action is not called as an argument, exit with message
#
if [ -z $ACTION ];
then
        echo "Usage $0: Define ACTION of backup or delete"
        exit 1
fi

# When calling script with delete argument, if no interval is provided, exit with message
#
if [ $ACTION = "delete" ] && [ -z $AGE ];
then
        echo "Please enter the age of backups you would like to delete"
        exit 2
fi

# When calling script with backup argument, if no volume id is provided, exit with message
#
if [ $ACTION = "backup" ] && [ -z $VOLUME ];
then
        echo "Please provide a volume id that you would like to backup"
        exit 3
fi

# Creates snapshot of volume and tag it with 'backup-script' description for tracking
#
function backup_ebs () {

        echo "Creating backup"
        aws ec2 create-snapshot --volume-id $VOLUME --description "backup-script"

}

function delete_snapshots () {
        # Parses all snapshot ID's
        for snapshot in $(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters Name=description,Values=backup-script | egrep "(SnapshotId)" | grep -o "snap\-\w\{8\}")
        do
            # Parses dates in "YYYY/MM/DD" format from snapshot ID's
            snapshotdate=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --filters Name=description,Values=backup-script | egrep "(StartTime)" | grep -o "\d\{4\}\-\d\{2\}\-\d\{2\}")
            startdate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")
            enddate=$(date -d $snapshotdate +"%Y-%m-%d")
            # Calculates the days since snapshot was created
            interval=$[ (startdate - enddate) / (60*60*24) ]
            if (( $interval >= $AGE ));
            then
                    aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $snapshot
            fi
        done
}

# Decides which function to call based on what action argument is provided when script is called
#
case $ACTION in
        "backup")
                backup_ebs
        ;;
        "delete")
                delete_snapshots
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: do your assignment within an if or a case statement:

```
case "$1" in 
    backup) VOLUME="$2";;
    delete) AGE="$2"; VOLUME="$3";;
esac
```

However, I would also avoid using global variables. So, I'd suggest passing those variables to your functions:

```
  backup_ebs "$VOLUME"
```

and

```
  delete_snapshots "$AGE"
```

This will ease maintaining that script

And if you prefer compact solution just exploit conditional assignment:

```
ACION="$1"
VOLUME="${3:-$2}"
AGE="$2"
```

Comment: I like the `case` statement; it avoids setting `AGE` at all if it won't be needed.

Comment: very nice solutions. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that you can view `backup` and `delete`+`3` as examples of a single variable-length argument, it might be better to make `VOLUME` first argument, since it is fixed for *all* commands.

```
bash -x backup vol-e5bf623b backup
bash -x backup vol-e5bf623b delete 3
```

Then in your script

```
VOLUME=$1
ACTION=$2
AGE=$3
```

Being able to make this kind of change easily is one of the benefits of naming the arguments, rather than using `$1` et al. sprinkled throughout your code.

Answer (score 0):

The positional arguments are set by position. The first argument is `$1` the second is `$2` and so on. If you want `$2` to be for delete and `$3` to be for backup then you need to use `backup backup '' vol-e5bf623b` when you run it (to pass an empty second argument).

That said, don't do that.

Just use the second argument as the argument for both. Either by giving it a generic name or by assigning it to an appropriately named variable *after* checking the mode.